# can i update my bitcoin qt 0.7 to 0.11 if my wallet has never synchronised and i'm still waiting to receive my bitcoins

Tags: wallet, synchronization

can some one please give me some solid advice as i am in need of my coins and it seems this is the best way to retrieve my coins but i cant risk losing my bitcoins! i have tried to create a raw transaction to my new multibit HD but cant get the command right!!!! as my IT literate nephew said that is an advanced way to go about it specialy since i know FA about IT work! lol. apparently updating my wallet can solve the slow synchronization. i have version 0.7 but wish to update to 0.11 or 0.10. will this work? how do i go about it? is there a high risk of losing my bitcoins? cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update from 0.7.* straight to 0.11.0 without problem. 0.7 is actually incapable of synchronizing with the network due to its age, so the upgrade is mandatory. When you open the new software it will rebuild the files on disk, and then resume synchronization (significantly faster than it was before). There is near zero chance of you losing your BTC by doing this, but make a backup of your wallet.dat file regardless just to be as safe as possible.

Comment: so how do i transfer my bitcoin qt 0.7 information to bitcoin core 0.11? or update 0.7 to 0.11? ive down loaded bitcoin core 0.11 but unsure how to transfer info over like the the address of my coins im desperately trying to get hold of and where im up to on the block chain synchronization???

Comment: Just update the software, it'll take care of everything under the hood. You don't need to make any changes other than to update the software.

Comment: sorry but that wont work!     it comes up with when i run install bitcoin qt 0.7.                                                                  a fatal error ocurred. bitcoin can no longer continue safely and will quit.     exception:st13runtime_error  cdb0:can't open database file blkindex.dat,error 22   c:\program files(86)\bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe in runaway exception                                                   so what can i do about this please???? am i screwed?

Comment: No matter what, as long as you have your wallet file you haven't lost any money. Why are you installing 0.7? You'll need to download 0.11.0 from Bitcoin.org to have any success synchronizing with the network.

Comment: i thought i can update by running the old and it will go to how i can update! so how do i transfer the info to bitcore core from my bitcoin qt 0.7? where do i need to go and what do i need to do please?

Comment: Bitcoin has no auto update function, the Bitcoin.org website has binaries you can download and install. There is no transfer of information necessary, just update the software. https://bitcoin.org/en/download

Comment: @peter hi ive downloaded and encrypted my bitcoin core wallet but my bitcoins that i never received from my bitcoin qt wallet because it never synced didnt automatically transfer over as said! what are my options of retrieving my bitcoins?